How to edit a cron expression at runtime in C# .NET?
I have an application with Quartz.NET that receives a cron expression as a string (e.g. 0 0 12 * * ? - Fire at 12pm (noon) every day) from a client, but I actually need the quartz job to trigger half an hour earlier.
The problem is I don't know what the cron expression will be ahead of time (so I can't just set the cron trigger to 0 30 11 * * ? - Fire at 11:30am every day).
Is there a generic way to edit an arbitrary cron expression so that it fires half an hour earlier?
I also thought about editing the Quartz.NET cron trigger (created from the original cron expression), but couldn't find how to do that.

Not sure the api exposes such a feature. Consider setting a time zone for the trigger that corresponds to your target zone minus 30m

Here is an idea - implement a decorator over CronTriggerImpl and override ComputeFirstFireTimeUtc and GetFireTimeAfter with the code that alters the timings the way you need it -
public class CronTriggerImplDecorator : AbstractTrigger, ICronTrigger
{
    private readonly CronTriggerImpl inner;
    ...
    public override DateTimeOffset? ComputeFirstFireTimeUtc(ICalendar? cal)
    ...
    public override DateTimeOffset? GetFireTimeAfter(DateTimeOffset? afterTime)

then define your schedule builder that returns the decorator -
public class CustomScheduleBuilder : IScheduleBuilder
{
    private readonly CronExpression cronExpression;

    public CustomScheduleBuilder(CronExpression cronExpression)
    {
        this.cronExpression = cronExpression;
    }

    private int misfireInstruction = MisfireInstruction.SmartPolicy;

    public IMutableTrigger Build()
    {
        CronTriggerImpl ct = new CronTriggerImpl();

        ct.CronExpression = cronExpression;
        ct.TimeZone = cronExpression.TimeZone;
        ct.MisfireInstruction = misfireInstruction;

        return new CronTriggerImplDecorator(ct);
    }
}

finally use the builder when constructing triggers -
.WithSchedule(new CustomScheduleBuilder(...))

